# How can I pass Int value to another class?

Tags: java, swing

I'm trying to make a button such that if the user clicks it, it would increment the value of int x, and in the other class I want to do the same but, it would increment the value of the x from the first class. I made this but I get an error when I pass the int value.Please help , I'm noob.

```
public class one extends JFrame{

    private JButton yes;
    private JButton no;
    private JLabel one;
    private JLabel pic;
    private JLabel two;
    public static int bla;

    public  static int x;


    public one(){
        super("The title");
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        yes = new JButton("yes");
        add(yes);

        no = new JButton("no");
        add(no);

        Icon one = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("one.jpg"));
        pic = new JLabel(one);
        add(pic);

        yes.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
            x++;
            setInt(x);
            printInt(x);
            new two().setVisible(true);

        }
        }
        );


    no.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
            x=0;
            setInt(x);
            printInt(x);
            new two().setVisible(true);
        }
        }
        );

    getx(x);


}
public void setInt(int y){
    y = x;
}

public Integer getx(int x){
    return x;
}

public void printInt(int y){
    System.out.printf("%s ", y);
}   
}
```

on another class

```
public class two extends JFrame {

    one satu = new one();
    x = x2;
```

I put x = x2 on the class two , but I got an error.Please help

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Answer (score 0):

To get and increment the value of `x` of your `one` class(poor class name; it's advisable to always begin class name with capital letter, so your class should be `One`) you should do:

```
One.x++;
```

from the other class.

Answer (score 0):

For your addActionListener insert `two.x++;` 
this will increment the value of x in the two class, and it will use the existing value of x from the two class.

```
yes.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {

   x++;
   setInt(x);
   printInt(x);
   two.x++; // This will increment int x in class two
   new two().setVisible(true);

   }
});
```

For your class two. Make your int x static, this will allow other classes to be able to interact with it's variables.

```
public class two {
// Make x static so that it can be seen by other public classes
static int x = 0; 
}
```